# On osx, how to open new iterm terminal tab from one script then run command in that temrinal window

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I am running osx. I have a script which runs the full stack then runs grunt at the end. I want to be able to separate running grunt in a separate terminal tab, i am using iterm.

I have tried something like

```
open -a Terminal "cd ~/dev/work/poc/user-interface/src/main/webapp; grunt"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you (obviously change dir & command):

```
osascript -e '
  tell app "iTerm"
    activate
    tell the first terminal
      launch session "Default Session"
      tell the last session
        set name to "New Session"
        write text "cd /usr/bin; ls"
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell'
```

It's a slightly modified version of [something I wrote](http://rud.is/b/2014/01/10/change-the-default-shell-action-in-rstudio-for-os-x/) to add iTerm support for RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e '
   tell application "Terminal"
   do script "date"
   activate
   end tell'
```

Replace `date` with whatever you want it to do.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `iterm` in your question, but I will leave it as it may help other folk.

Comment: I don't have iTerm, but you can maybe adapt the code here and wrap it in the `osascript` call like I did for the standard Apple term... https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript